# How do I merge material slots?

Tags: materials

I have a complex shape with many materials assigned to it so I can't just easily pick faces to those to apply this material, so how do I reduce 3 slots that have the exact same material into one slot on one shape?

Comment: You will have to learn to work with UV unwrap and create mask for complex material

Comment: There are no UV maps on this shape.

Comment: you will have to create one.

Comment: if your materials are duplicates with .001, .002 extensions, then you can enable the addon Materials Utils Specials and then open the specials menu (arrow down icon next to material slots) and go to Specials -> Merge Base Names

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know there is no automatic way to merge material slots in one single step, you can however easily select all faces with a certain material applied and assing any other material to them.

Say you have material A, B and C and want to have only A and B. In the *Properties Window > Materials* select material slot A and press the *Select* button below, then select material slot B and click the *Assign* button, and you will have technically 'merged' both slots.

You can now delete material slot C by selecting it and pressing the [-] button to the right.

Comment: You can select faces that have a certain material. That was the part I didn't know that Blender has as an option. 

Thanks Duarte

Answer (score 4):

There is now way how to *merge* materials to make some kind of new mixed material.
But often an imported model can contain many duplicates of the same material with extensions like .001, .002 etc. - if this is your case, you can try this:

- Enable **Materials Utils**

  [image]
- Navigate to object's materials tab and go to *Material Specials Menu* -> *Specials* -> *Merge Base Names*

  [image]
- Alternatively, you can try luck with enabling another built-in addon called **Datablock Tools** and go to *Object* -> *Datablock Tools* -> *Clean Materials Datablock*

  [image]

Hopefully some of the methods will work for you.

Answer (score 3):

Merge materials in 3 easy steps.

This is your materials list:

- RED
- GREEN
- BLUE

If you want to make all that's BLUE to be RED. 
1) Select the BLUE material. 
2) Use the up arrow till the BLUE is under the RED. 
3) Delete the BLUE by using the minus button. 
Done! 
Now all that was BLUE is now RED.

The way Blender behaves if you delete a material all the material that used that slot will inherit the slot above unless it is the top slot then it will inherit the one below.