# How delete duplicate materials and armature post import, or can I import without duplication?

Tags: materials, linked-data

[image]

When I import different models into the scene with the same material and the armature, everything is duplicated and I can’t work normally in the engine with this later. How to fix it?

Comment: Check this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/91024/32374

Comment: this works only in 1 object materials properties

Comment: This can be scripted easily, but I don’t think there’s a built-in tool to do this.